# How to get started with a Bitcoin wallet

Tags: blockchain.info

Where should I go to start a wallet? I have downloaded the TOR browser and got online at WEUSECOINS.COM.  Is there another site, perhaps one with more information for beginners, that I should be using?

Comment: The official wiki is an excellent place to start: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Main_Page

Answer (score 2):

No need for Tor at all (unless you intend to buy drugs or weapons, but in that case you're better off using cash dollars or euros).

I'd recommend to read up on Bitcoin to understand what you're doing. Then you can find an [overview of wallets on bitcoin.org](https://bitcoin.org/en/choose-your-wallet), but for a quick start, the fastest way to get started is:

- Desktop (Windows/Mac/Linux) : [Electrum](https://electrum.org) or [MultiBit](https://multibit.org)
- Android : [Bitcoin Wallet](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.schildbach.wallet) by Andreas Schildbach
- iOS : [Bread Wallet](https://itunes.apple.com/app/breadwallet/id885251393)
- Windows phone : Get an Android phone instead
- Web wallet, accessible anywhere : [Coinpunk](https://coinpunk.com/)

These are all fairly easy to use, and don't bother you with all kinds of advanced options.

Comment: In fact, using Tor is harmful for non-technical users as it subjects them to man-in-the-middle attacks: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/30335/is-the-threat-of-computer-malware-to-steal-bitcoin-exaggerated